# R - Iterate over csv file by row and sum in groups of 5

Tags: r, csv, row, infinite-loop

I have a data structure created using read.csv() of dimensions 130, 395. I am trying to iterate over the data by row and return a vector containing a list of lists of the sum over each row in increments of 5 (only from data[,13:395]). I have written the following code, but it returns a vector with sums over intervals of 5 by column and it is also an infinite loop. In other words, I am trying to figure how to make this code finite and work by row.

```
data <- read.csv(file = "Table.csv")
indexes <- c(13:395)
counter <- 0
a <- c()
list <- c()

for(line in data){
    for(index in indexes){
        while(counter<5){
            a <- c(a, line[index])
            counter = counter + 1
            }
        list <- c(list, sum(a, na.rm = TRUE))
        counter = 0
        a = c()
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: There are several questions I could ask here, but we'll start with: what do you expect to happen when you reach index 391 in a given row? In that case there aren't 5 values ahead of it to add.

Comment: Sum the last four and move on to the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(zoo)
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:100,nrow = 4))
> t(apply(d,1,function(x) { rollapply(x,width = 5,FUN = "mean",align = "left") }))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]    9   13   17   21   25   29   33   37   41    45    49    53    57    61    65    69    73    77    81    85
[2,]   10   14   18   22   26   30   34   38   42    46    50    54    58    62    66    70    74    78    82    86
[3,]   11   15   19   23   27   31   35   39   43    47    51    55    59    63    67    71    75    79    83    87
[4,]   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40   44    48    52    56    60    64    68    72    76    80    84    88
     [,21]
[1,]    89
[2,]    90
[3,]    91
[4,]    92
```

For your purposes, you'd only pass columns `13:365` (i.e. something like `d[,13:365]` instead of just `d`).

I see now that I used `mean` instead of `sum` by mistake, but that change is easy to make.

Comment: I have never used pkg zoo and am not quite sure what the output is, could you explain what this matrix contains? It seems like it would be useful if it contained the values of the cells [in the csv] because then I could sum over the values in the matrix.

Comment: @AidanQuinn Each row contains the mean of each successive group of 5 values from each row in `d`. To do sums, just replace `FUN = "mean"` with `FUN = "sum"`. (Also, your example code above exhibited a ton of pretty classic mistakes that new R users run into that will make you _really_ unhappy down the road. The [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) is one good reference.)

Comment: Thanks, I see. When I run this it seems to still sum by column, not row but I will continue to work on it. Thanks for the reference too.

Comment: @AidanQuinn If you examine my example closely you'll see that it is definitely working by row. Note that the first _column_ of `d` is 1,2,3,4 and the mean of those values is most certainly not 9, the 1,1 entry of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps meaning something like this:

```
lapply(1:nrow(data),function(i) rowSums(data[i:min(i+5,nrow(data)),13:395]))
```

The initial results using a built in dataset are:

```
 head(lapply(1:nrow(mtcars),function(i) rowSums(mtcars[i:min(i+5,nrow(mtcars)),])))
[[1]]
        Mazda RX4     Mazda RX4 Wag        Datsun 710    Hornet 4 Drive 
          328.980           329.795           259.580           426.135 
Hornet Sportabout           Valiant 
          590.310           385.540 

[[2]]
    Mazda RX4 Wag        Datsun 710    Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout 
          329.795           259.580           426.135           590.310 
          Valiant        Duster 360 
          385.540           656.920 

[[3]]
       Datsun 710    Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout           Valiant 
          259.580           426.135           590.310           385.540 
       Duster 360         Merc 240D 
          656.920           270.980 

[[4]]
   Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout           Valiant        Duster 360 
          426.135           590.310           385.540           656.920 
        Merc 240D          Merc 230 
          270.980           299.570 

[[5]]
Hornet Sportabout           Valiant        Duster 360         Merc 240D 
           590.31            385.54            656.92            270.98 
         Merc 230          Merc 280 
           299.57            350.46 

[[6]]
   Valiant Duster 360  Merc 240D   Merc 230   Merc 280  Merc 280C 
    385.54     656.92     270.98     299.57     350.46     349.66
```